# How to take a screenshot in WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, screenshot, c++-cx

How to produce a complete WP8 screenshot? By “complete” I mean “including application bar, status bar, message boxes and keyboard”.

Things I’ve tried:

GDI API that worked in WP7 (GetDC, CreateCompatibleDC, BitBlt), result - CreateCompatibleDC or CreateDCW  return NULL, GetLastError says “the specified procedure could not be found”. Moreover, it seems WP8 only has the single HDC, namely 0x00dc00dc, so no off-screen GDI DCs are possible.

InvokeScreenCapture and SaveApplicationScreenShot from ShellChrome.dll – application deactivates, nothing else happens.

D3D11Device1::GetImmediateContext, ID3D11RenderTargetView::OMGetRenderTargets – OMGetRenderTargets returns NULL.

Any other ideas?

I don’t need to pass marketplace certification, so unsupported/undocumented APIs are OK.

Comment: Beytan, that method doesn't capture any non-Silverlight UI elements (application bar, message box, keyboard, status bar).

Comment: I was expecting that, needed to be sure. ok then.

Comment: You can press Windows Key and the Power button, or use the emulator screenshot tool, but there's no programmatic way that I know of.

Comment: Paul, I need the programmatic way.. By a chance, do you know which process or module handles the Win+Power combination? I live in a country where reverse engineering for legitimate purposes is perfectly legal..

Comment: Even if there was a way to hack the Win+Power combination you wouldn't get such an app through the store submission/verification process so what would be the point?   If it was your app you were taking the image of you would know what the ApplicationBar should look like so you could add that to the image captured programmatically if you REALLY needed it.

Comment: Matt, I've specified in my question I don't need to pass marketplace certification. WP8 has 3 different screen sizes * 2 orientations. And becides application bar, there're other non-silverlight UI elements, such as soft keyboard, and message boxes.

Answer (score 0):

In WP8 and under there is no way to capture the entire screen without running in TCB (requires a hacked image) and loading in libs that don't ship with any SDK.

Comment: I've already created a few libs that don't ship with any SDK (e.g. ext-ms-win-gdi-dc-create-l1-1-0.lib). Do you know the API that does what I want?

Comment: Also, your "and under" is wrong: in WP7, GetDC, CreateCompatibleDC, BitBlt work great, here's the XAP: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1316199